# Generic cut, copy, paste short cut keys for windows form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I have different forms having text input fields in them. How do I enable the cut, copy and paste shortcut keys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, for all fields?

Comment: I don't think you have to do anything.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. If you put a TextBox control on a Windows Form it automatically responds correctly to Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V. Unless you've done something custom, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Just get their ASCII code and allow them to perform functionality according to your requirement e.g

```
var youkey=keycode;
if(keycode==27)
{
//your action
}
else if
{
// your action
}
....
```